# How to launch Youtube application to open a channel?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I want to access from my application to youtube to open a channel. I've searched for a solution but i just found how to open/stream a video :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:VIDEO_ID"));
startActivity(i);
```

But what about opening directly a channel?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlStr));
startActivity(intent);
```

if you use the url of a youtube channel such as: http://www.youtube.com/user/JustinBieberVEVO

this should give you the option to open youtube to the given channel.

hope this helps!

Comment: I was hoping the link was not actually beiber but something, really anything, else.  Oh well. Thanks for the intent tip.

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer is late and such but i wanted to share this anyway. This worked for me:

`vnd.youtube://user/channel/channel_id`

This opens the channel directly in the youtube app. Without asking the user.

**Update**

Didn't include any code because i was using **React Native**, and maybe people is looking for native code. Anyway here you go:

```
Linking
    .openURL( 'vnd.youtube://user/channel/' + channel_id )
    .catch( ... )
```

But, **i think** in **native code** it should be something like this:

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://user/channel/" + channel_id));
try {
  context.startActivity(appIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) { ... }
```

*I'm not too familiarized with native code so it may be wrong, but should work like a guide*.

Comment: You should an explain or more information or included the code

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. hope that helps a little bit.

Comment: Best . Everything is achieved with practice! @marcoaguayo1915

Comment: `vnd.youtube://channel/' + channel_id` works for me (without `user`).

Answer (score 2):

```
vnd.youtube://channel/channel_id
```

For custon URL
vnd.youtube://c/channel_permalink